# how to exit specific Session object (logout) asp

Tags: c#

I have a login method , where each user inserts his name into a specific session,
so that means his logged in.

But , I want to be able to go through all the available sessions -
and check :

if the user is a specific user - cause him to logout (exit the session).

and if the user is not a specific user , keep searching.

any idea how do I do that?

Comment: do you do it as an excercise? These days frameworks like asp.net have built in authentication, so you don't have to do these things yourself + it is going to be much better for security. There is a built in project template with login feature in  asp.net.

Comment: I said something stupid here. I commented that I just wanted more control over the website, and since the session object was technically inside my computer's memory (I said hardrive, but I meant ram) I should be able to access it. I found that annoying, so I started using django instead.